# JSON.NET - Merge and ContainsKey don't work in v11.0.1 -> v13.0.2

Tags: c#, json, .net, reference

I am unable to get my VS .NET project to work with these two JSON.NET functions, other functions within JSON.NET work fine just these two don't exist (also don't appear in object browser).

**Error Messages:**

Error   CS1061  'JObject' does not contain a definition for 'Merge' and no extension method 'Merge' accepting a first argument of type 'JObject' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Error   CS1061  'JObject' does not contain a definition for 'ContainsKey' and no extension method 'ContainsKey' accepting a first argument of type 'JObject' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I've removed and added the references both via .dll and NuGet - issue still appears.

I have tried v11.0.1, v12.0.3, v13.0.0 and v13.0.2.

using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq; is used.

The use case is that there is code that has a setup file which defines parameters for a test but the code needs to support legacy .json files. So using a version number and checking if the version parameter exists sets how to respond to each test.

Then there are two objects and when generating (exporting) the .json the two objects are merged this also throws error.

**Code:**

```
JObject setup = new JObject
(
    new JProperty("Version", "1.2")
);

JObject param = new JObject
(
    new JProperty("Parameter", "lang")
    new JProperty("Value", "en")
);

setup.Merge(param);

if (setup.ContainsKey("Version"))
{
    //code
}
```

Comment: You have to show the code you have tried so far. these functions depend on the context. They  will work only with collections

Comment: I _guess_ you unintentionally created your own JObject class somewhere in your project (within a namespace that is equal or closer than the Newtonsoft.Json namespace to the namespace containing the code affected by the eror). If my _suspicion_ is correct, no amount of removing or adding of the Newtonsoft.Json library would change that, and you would have to find the duplicate JObject class definition in your project and eliminate it from your project.

Comment: @Serge I have made these edits

Comment: And `config` is...? Should we just guess? ;-)

Comment: @MySkullCaveIsADarkPlace I cannot see any JObject classes other than the within the Newtonsoft.Json.Linq and config is meant to be setup lol

Comment: If you are using Visual Studio, move the cursor caret onto "JObject" in the line `JObject setup = new JObject` and press F12. This will lead you to the declaration of the used JObject type. Check the name of the tab and the very first three lines of the source code file that you see after pressing F12. What do they say?

Comment: Another suspicion: Perhaps your project uses another package/dependency that pulls in a much older Newtonsoft.Json version. Checking the commit history for the JObject/JContainer classes in the Newtonsoft.Json Github repo, i see that JObject.ContainsKey has been made public some time in 2017, and JContainer.Merge some time in 2014. If for some reason your build folder ends up with an older Newtonsoft.Json library version prior to these commits, this could explain the lacking/inaccessible methods...

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to merge objects. You need the collection. In this case you can use Properties collection and Concat operator

```
JObject result =  new JObject( setup.Properties().Concat(param.Properties() ));
    

if (result.Properties().Any(x => x.Name == "Version"))
{
        //code
}
```